# AVAudioRecorder crashes after view disappears

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, crash, avaudiorecorder

To record audio I show a new View as subview and after recording I remove the subview within it with RemoveFromSuperview. Just to describe how I handle the overlay.

The problem is, after recording with AVAudioRecorder the application crashed sometimes immediately after removing the overlay view and sometimes when the superview will disappear.

The crash logs looks like the following:

```
Incident Identifier: 65BE4068-D7BE-4F3F-B739-00006CAB74CC
CrashReporter Key:   d97865bbdce37e60edb2f77974b8b86911a1007e
Hardware Model:      iPad4,1
Process:             B2MobileBjiOS [8764]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/3C397A5D-B00B-40CE-BCF8-0C6836B0EBB2/B2MobileBjiOS.app/B2MobileBjiOS
Identifier:          ch.bauplus.mobile.bj.trunk
Version:             30 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-01-20 13:54:04.160 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39f8a1fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39ff1a4f pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39f3b029 abort + 73
3   B2MobileBjiOS                   0x01607d95 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2335)
4   B2MobileBjiOS                   0x01612a99 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (mini.c:6744)
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x39fec721 _sigtramp + 41
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2e2db0b3 -[AVAudioRecorder dealloc] + 119
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2e2db0b3 -[AVAudioRecorder dealloc] + 119
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x399e5b07 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 171
9   B2MobileBjiOS                   0x016bfb00 monotouch_release_managed_ref (monotouch-glue.m:1296)
10  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x0109629c wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject_monotouch_release_managed_ref_intptr + 88
11  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x00cb31d8 MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject_ReleaseManagedRef + 28
12  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x00cb559c MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject_NSObject_Disposer_Drain_MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject + 360
13  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x006802cc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 196
14  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x01614b75 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:6610)
15  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x0165c77b mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2827)
16  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x0158e7e7 native_to_managed_trampoline_MonoTouch_Foundation_NSObject_NSObject_Disposer_Drain (registrar.m:344)
17  Foundation                      0x2fd22e47 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 383
18  CoreFoundation                  0x2f309f1d __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 13
19  CoreFoundation                  0x2f309469 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 337
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2f307bd3 __CFRunLoopRun + 627
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2f27246d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
22  CoreFoundation                  0x2f27224f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
23  GraphicsServices                0x33f732e7 GSEventRunModal + 135
24  UIKit                           0x31b27841 UIApplicationMain + 1133
25  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x010e1af8 wrapper_managed_to_native_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 268
26  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x00d617f4 MonoTouch_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 296
27  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x002062f4 B2.Mobile.Bj.iOS.Application:Main (Main.cs:16)
28  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x006802cc wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 196
29  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x01614b75 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:6610)
30  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x0165c77b mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2827)
31  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x016604f9 mono_runtime_exec_main (object.c:4052)
32  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x01660349 mono_runtime_run_main (object.c:3678)
33  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x015fec5d mono_jit_exec (driver.g.c:1009)
34  B2MobileBjiOS                   0x016a95cc main (main.m:489)
35  libdyld.dylib                   0x39ed3ab5 start + 1
```

AudioRecordingOverlay.cs

```cs
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Timers;
using B2.Mobile.Common.iOS;

namespace B2.Mobile.Common.Ui.iOS
{
    public class AudioRecordingOverlay : UIView
    {
        private const int OverlaySize = 120;
        private const int ImageSize = 60;

        private readonly Timer _timer;
        private readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch;
        private readonly UITapGestureRecognizer _tapGesture;
        private readonly AudioHelper _audioRecorder;

        private UIView _overlay;
        private UIButton _button;
        private UILabel _label;
        private string _audioUrl;

        public Action<string> ClosedAction { get; set; }

        public AudioRecordingOverlay(string filename, RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
        {
            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            _timer = new Timer(1000);
            _timer.AutoReset = true;
            _timer.Elapsed += HandleElapsed;
            _tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(TapGestureAction);
            _audioRecorder = new AudioHelper(filename);

            InitializeUI();
        }

        public void InitializeUI()
        {
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 255, 255, 200);
            AddGestureRecognizer(_tapGesture);

            var xOverlay = (Bounds.Width - OverlaySize) / 2;
            var yOverlay = (Bounds.Height - OverlaySize) / 2;
            _overlay = new UIView(new RectangleF(xOverlay, yOverlay, OverlaySize, OverlaySize));
            _overlay.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(255, 255, 255, 127);
            _overlay.Layer.CornerRadius = 5.0f;
            _overlay.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            _overlay.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 127).CGColor;
            AddSubview(_overlay);

            // Start / Stop / Status
            var xButton = (OverlaySize - ImageSize) / 2;
            var yButton = 20;
            _button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            _button.Frame = new RectangleF(xButton, yButton, 60, 60);
            _button.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Images/microphone-large.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
            _button.TouchUpInside += RecordButtonClicked;
            _overlay.AddSubview(_button);

            // Timer
            _label = new UILabel();
            _label.Frame = new RectangleF(20, ImageSize + 30, _overlay.Bounds.Width - 40, _label.Font.LineHeight);
            _label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            _label.Text = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss");
            _overlay.AddSubview(_label);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            if (_stopwatch.IsRunning)
                return;

            _stopwatch.Reset();
            _stopwatch.Start();
            _timer.Start();
            _button.TintColor = UIColor.Red;

            _audioRecorder.StartRecording();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (!_stopwatch.IsRunning)
                return;

            _stopwatch.Stop();
            _timer.Stop();
            _button.TintColor = TintColor;

            _audioRecorder.StopRecording();
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _audioUrl = _audioRecorder.Save();
        }

        public void Discard()
        {
            _audioRecorder.Discard();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            if (ClosedAction != null)
                ClosedAction(_audioUrl);

            RemoveFromSuperview();
        }

        void RecordButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (_stopwatch.IsRunning)
            {
                Stop();

                using (var alert = new UIAlertView("Aufnahme", "Soll die Aufnahme gespeichert werden?", null, "Nein", new[] { "Ja" }))
                {
                    alert.Clicked += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.ButtonIndex == 0)
                        {
                            Discard();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Save();
                        }

                        Close();
                    };

                    alert.Show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Start();
            }
        }

        private void HandleElapsed (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    _label.Text = _stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm\\:ss");
                });
        }

        private void TapGestureAction(UITapGestureRecognizer recognizer)
        {
            if (_stopwatch.IsRunning)
            {
                using (var alert = new UIAlertView("Aufnahme", "Soll die Aufnahme gestoppt und gespeichert werden?", null, "Nein", new[] { "Ja" }))
                {
                    alert.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
                    {
                        if (e.ButtonIndex != 0)
                        {
                            Stop();
                            Save();
                            Close();
                        }
                    };

                    alert.Show();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveFromSuperview();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AudioHelper.cs

```cs
using System;
using MonoTouch.AVFoundation;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.IO;

namespace B2.Mobile.Common.iOS
{
    public class AudioHelper
    {
        private AVAudioRecorder _recorder;
        private readonly string _filename;
        private NSUrl _audioUrl;
        private AVAudioSession _session;
        private AVAudioPlayer _player;

        public Action FinishedPlayingAction {get;set;}

        public AudioHelper(string filename)
        {
            _filename = filename;
        }

        public void Play()
        {
            NSError error = null;
            _player = new AVAudioPlayer(new NSUrl(_filename), error);
            _player.PrepareToPlay();
            _player.FinishedPlaying += (sender, e) => 
            {
                if (FinishedPlayingAction != null)
                    FinishedPlayingAction();
            };

            _session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
            _session.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryPlayback, out error);
            _session.SetActive(true, out error);

            _player.Play();
        }

        public void Continue()
        {
            if (_player != null)
                _player.Play();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (_player != null)
                _player.Stop();
        }

        public void Pause()
        {
            if (_player != null)
                _player.Pause();
        }

        public void StartRecording()
        {
            _recorder = new AVAudioRecorder();
            _session = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();

            NSError error;
            _session.SetCategory(AVAudioSession.CategoryRecord, out error);
            if(error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
                return;
            }

            _session.SetActive(true, out error);
            if(error != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
                return;
            }

            if(!PrepareAudioRecording())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Aufnahme fehlgeschlagen");
            }

            if(!_recorder.Record())
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Aufnahme fehlgeschlagen");
            }
        }

        public void StopRecording()
        {
            if (!_recorder.Recording)
                return;

            _recorder.Stop();
        }

        public string Save()
        {
            return _audioUrl.Path;
        }

        public void Discard()
        {
            try
            {
                File.Delete(_audioUrl.Path);
            }
            catch 
            {
            }
        }

        private bool PrepareAudioRecording()
        {
            //Declare string for application temp path and tack on the file extension
            var tempRecording = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), _filename);

            Console.WriteLine(tempRecording);
            _audioUrl = NSUrl.FromFilename(tempRecording);

            var audioSettings = new AudioSettings
            {
                SampleRate = 44100.0f, 
                Format = MonoTouch.AudioToolbox.AudioFormatType.MPEG4AAC,
                NumberChannels = 1,
                AudioQuality = AVAudioQuality.High
            };

            //Set recorder parameters
            NSError error;
            _recorder = AVAudioRecorder.Create(_audioUrl, audioSettings, out error);
            if((_recorder == null) || (error != null))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
                return false;
            }

            //Set Recorder to Prepare To Record
            if(!_recorder.PrepareToRecord())
            {
                _recorder.Dispose();
                _recorder = null;
                return false;
            }

            _recorder.FinishedRecording += (sender, e) => 
            {
                _recorder.Dispose();
                _recorder = null;
                Console.WriteLine("Done Recording (status: {0})", e.Status);
            };

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with AVAudioRecorder. AVAudioRecorder crashes on object release if it is created using constructor without arguments.

You can easily reproduce the crash with C#:

```
var recorder = new AVAudioRecorder();
recorder.Dispose();
```

or with Swift (even in playground):

```
var recorder: AVAudioRecorder? = AVAudioRecorder()
recorder = nil
```

In your code, you initialize  `_recorder` using `new AVAudioRecorder();`, so when it is garbage collected you got an exception during disposing of the object.

Simply create the recorder with 'right' constructor.

`AVAudioRecorder.Create(NSUrl url, AudioSettings settings, out NSError error);`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be closing the view while the recorder is still recording. Add stop call to your Close function (or make Close private) and don't call RemoveFromSuperview until the recorder has actually stopped. Override Dispose function to see what the recorder status is when it is called.

Also this seems to be redundant allocation:

```
_recorder = new AVAudioRecorder();
```

Do you need all those public functions; Save, Close, Discard...?